# Amazon API Gateway unable to call Lambda in VPC

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

When I'm moving my AWS Lambda function inside an RDS MySQL VPC, then the API Gateway cannot call it and timeouts. Is it possible to call a VPC Lambda from API Gateway?

VPC Links cannot be created with Application Load Balancers that is the only choice for a Lambda function, they need Network Load Balancers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that it's not your lambda that is timing out. API Gateway has no problem calling Lambda functions that are configured to run inside a VPC.

Consider using a VPC service endpoint for KMS and/or other services you need if you need your lambda to run in a VPC. Depending on the services this might be cheaper than a NAT gateway.

Comment: You were right. I was decrypting a class variable using KMS, but it turns out that it needs internet access. You were right, no problem for calling a VPC Lambda function from API Gateway. Thanx.